# Warning: "This app will not work with future versions of iOS"

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have an iPad with iOS 10.3 installed. Some apps are triggering a popup warning:

**"SomeApp" needs to be updated.
This app will not work with future versions of iOS.**

It is something related with 32 or 64 bits? I am using last version of Xcode.

Comment: yes!! read this article : https://www.macrumors.com/2017/01/31/32-bit-apps-wont-work-on-future-ios-versions/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's probably related to 64bit support. Make sure that in your build settings under architectures ARM64 is present.

[image]

Comment: @Tripwire i have already added arm64 but still getting the alert. Don't know why?

Comment: @V.J. can you post your build settings?

Comment: @Tripwire I did it. Actually alert came because my app's deployment target is 7.0. So to remove it i made the deployment target to 8.0. Now it will work fine.. Thank you too.. :)